# Work from home policy canceled for "fairness", yet two senior level managers work 100% remotely. Discriminatory benefits?

Tags: human-resources, telecommute, discrimination, equality, work-from-home

Our company enables online education (*irony*) and has about 100+ employees. After alleged abuse of the work from home (WFH) "policy" (since there was no real policy aside from your manager being ok with it) in one department, the policy was canceled for everyone in the company.

However, at least two of the senior managers (direct reports to the CEO) work completely from home, and manage large teams, have been exempted from this policy. Both are the same gender as the CEO and are very buddy-buddy with the CEO (one is personal friend hired recently, one is a long time employee working in another state). IT, Marketing, HR, etc. had people who would work one day a week from home - however that's come to an abrupt halt and all requests for an exemption have been denied.

In speaking with HR, I found out they disapproved of their split on WFH, but were powerless to stop them. I also discovered they seemed to anticipate legal issues and said the managers "had remote working as a stipulation of their contract" - thus were allowed to continue (very suspicious: not sure if that was originally in their contracts or amended to be in it recently).

I hesitate to say it's as far as discrimination (especially because I probably wouldn't fall under any protected category), but it certainly feels like unfair workplace treatment. I've already started looking, but I equally want to challenge this disparity in our benefits before my departure. At the very least, I'd like to write an open letter to the CEO after leaving, sharing my thoughts on these practices.

What's the best way to challenge this policy moving forward?

Comment: Are you a senior manager too?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Voting to close as this is not on topic for the workplace

Comment: Pare it down to the essence of your question and you've got a much better chance of it staying opening or reopening when it's closed.  You're really all over the place here. [ask]

Comment: Thank you Chris, I've removed the extra details and tried to be more direct. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why on earth do you think a letter to the CEO after you leave would make the slightest difference? That is just having a snit and it reflects poorly on you in the marketplace for the same reason you don't bash your current employer in a job interview. If you are going to leave, why do you care? For the record, I have never worked for any company where senior managers didn't get better benefits than regular employees, so this isn't unusual. The person working from a different physical location most likely did specify that he or she would be 100% when accepting the offer,

Comment: With all due respect, I don't know if anyone from the internet can help you with your question **"What's the best way to challenge this policy moving forward?**.  As this is a company policy given to your coworkers.

Comment: Executives treat each other and their buddies differently than the wage slaves under them? Shocking.

Comment: Policy only reflects its own enforcement. In other words, they're enforcing it for you, but not for them. Thus, that's the policy going forward.

Answer (score 5):

Working from home is not a "benefit" per se. It's merely a location where you're allowed to work.

As such, unless they were saying "all asians" or "all women" can't work from home or something similar, you really have nothing to cry discrimination about. It's a choice they made to benefit their most key and trusted employees, which apparently are only themselves.

There's really nothing you can do aside from dealing with it or moving on.

You can address things with the CEO after leaving, but the reality is that he won't care. You're a peon, he's the boss. In his eyes, you're just a disgruntled employee.

Leaving a company is like a divorce. When you leave, it's best to be done with it. Appreciate it for the good times you had but know that it's time to go. And that's ok. There's really no need to "lob a bomb" when you leave. Just be happy for what there was to be happy about and move on completely.  Otherwise you're still emotionally hanging around.

Comment: yep, company policy can dictate and they can make it whatever they want so long as it doesn't include race/religion/gender/age/etc...  I have seen it on tenure of service as well as "they already are, but no new people" etc...  Sorry it sucks, but recommend you find somewhere else if you want to keep being remote.